# Fastest way to replace elements of a file's path and extension?

Tags: python

Given the path of a file:

```
file = "/directory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.jpg"
```

How can I quickly replace it with:

```
new_file = "/newdirectory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.MOV"
```

Changing both directory for "newdirectory" and ".jpg" for ".MOV"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this can be done in different way's, but this is how I would do

First change the extension. This can be easily done via [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) something like

```
path = "/directory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.jpg"
new_file=os.path.splitext(path)[0]+".MOV"
```

This gives the path as

```
"/directory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.MOV"
```

Now to change the directory to newdirectory, we can use [str.split, with maxsplit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) option.

```
new_file=new_file.split('/',2)
```

and finally use [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.join), replacing the second item in the list with your favorite directory  with '/' as the delimiter

```
new_file = '/'.join([new_file[0],"newdirectory",new_file[2]])
```

So finally we have

```
"/newdirectory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.MOV"
```

So to summarize, it boils down to three lines

```
new_file=os.path.splitext(path)[0]+".MOV"
new_file=new_file.split('/',2)
new_file = '/'.join([new_file[0],"newdirectory",new_file[2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep)

```
import os

path = "/directory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.jpg"

path = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + '.mov'

path = path.split(os.sep, 2)
path[1] = 'newdirectory'
path = os.sep.join(path)

print path
```

**Result:**

```
/newdirectory/date/2011/2009-01-11 This is a file's path/file.mov
```